# Trying to reach the Alpha Bay marketplace first time using Tor

Tags: onion-routing, tor-install, directory, darknet, spoofing

I am trying to buy something on Alpha Bay but I am not sure how to get to the Alpha Bay website and how do I know it's the real one and not a spoofed mirror site.

I am using an iPhone and just went to the iPhone app store and downloaded an app called Tor Browser. When I went on it, the homepage is just a Microsoft Bing search bar, so I typed alphabay and a wiki page was listed first, then a bunch of other results listings, with most of them saying things in the headline like the best darknet markets websites etc... but no listing for Alpha Bay.

Can someone explain how I can get on Alpha Bay and be sure it's the real site? I read there are a ton of spoofed mirror sites that look exactly like the real one, but you will send your Bitcoin to what you think is a legitimate vendor on Alpha Bay and then you won't receive the product because you used a duped replica scam site.

Also besides Alpha Bay, what are a couple of other established legitimate market places - and like my question above, how do I find the URL and access them, and what can I do to ensure I am using the authentic marketplace website?

I am in need of a certain anxiety medication and was told I could obtain it cheaply on the dark web since I don't have health insurance. Just FYI it's a legal medication and not a controlled substance so I wouldn't be breaking any laws.

Anyone who can help with a step by step explanation that's easy to understand on how I can use the dark web on my phone to access either Alpha Bay or another legitimate marketplace would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers:

1. Please understand what it is that you are downloading. Tor is run by The [Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/). There is no official Tor Browser for iphones, but the Tor Projects suggests that you use one called [Onion Browser](https://support.torproject.org/tormobile/tormobile-3/).
2. We will not give you URLs for Onion marketplaces on this site. Check with Reddit's [r/onions](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/) subreddit.